# need information on Zamco motorbike

Tags: mini-bike

I can't find any information about Zamco bikes online. Are they only shipped to Jamaica? Where can I get more information on these bikes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Shopping questions are off-topic here, this is about maintenance and repair. I'm sure the web will be full of answers though.

Comment: Well if everyone here is like you I might as discontinue from this site. How is my question a shopping question?

Comment: You're looking for information on where to buy a motorbike, that's a shopping question. Questions on driving/riding techniques and tire wear are also off topic. The reason these are off-topic is to keep's the site's focus on maintenance and repair. All StackExchange sites have on and off topic rules, and it works really well. Once you have a bike and have a question on how to maintain or fix it please feel free to run it by us, until then I hope you find a good one.

Comment: @GdD where in my question did I mention buying a bike. All I did was ask where I can get information about the bike. Information sir. Which can help me to maintain and repair the bike.